# Making css auto slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/) 3D cube animation slider. The problem with this slider is that it needs to click to see the next picture. I want auto silder. All the 4 images should slide automatically and when the image is 4 then the next image will be image 1 again.

```
$("#controls").on('click', 'span', function(){
    $(".cubeSpinner").css("transform","rotateY("+($(this).index() * -90)+"deg)");
});
```

I am new to programming. Can anyone help me how to customize this make it auto slider without clicking the images?

Comment: What do you mean by auto slide. Do you mean you want this cube to rotate without user interaction.

Comment: yes rotate without any interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/21/

Change your javascript to this.

```
var index = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    if(index==3)
        index = 0;
    $(".cubeSpinner").css("transform","rotateY("+(index * -90)+"deg)");
    index++;
},1500);
```

Comment: thanks but after the image 4 it is calling image 1 by rotating anit clockwise direction. I dont want this it should call image 1 just like moving from image 2 to image3

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to trigger click.

```
var count=0;
    var len = $('#controls span').length;

    setInterval(function(){
        if(count === len){
            count = 0;
        }
        $('#controls span').eq(count).trigger('click');
        count++;
    }, 5000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K99GS/23/)